# how can we define register width with variable value

Tags: variables, verilog

I have taken a counter variable 'n' in initial block which I counts some value. After counting I want to use this as width for some 'reg a'.
So can I declare may register as reg [n:0] a
When I tried this it gives an error that r is not constant....is there any way to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do that. A Verilog description is meant to be translated into some sort of electronic circuit, and these cannot change the number of bits of their buses dynamically.

All you can do is to define `a` with the maximum width you will use, and then just use the number of bits accordingly with the value of `n`

Another thing you can do (but I think it does of not use here) is to define a `reg` with a parametrized width. This is not the same as defining a `reg` with a variable width, though, as the value of the parameter must be known at compile time.

Comment: what if I do it with passing value of n from one module to other. Because I am using 'n' for specifying width of a ram I want to access.

Comment: `n` will have a maximum value, so make your RAM to be of that maximum value. When you do the access, include logic to discard bits of RAM you don't want, according to the value of `n`. Just think that what you describe is meant to be engraved in silicon, so it is inmutable. Whatever thing you do in the description that needs dynamic reconfiguration, is not (at least yet) allowed.

Comment: I understood your point and implemented likewise. But in most cases I end up in wasting number of address lines. Is there any alternate for this.

Comment: Mmmmm.... maybe using some sort of multiplexion: transmiting address bits by a fixed number of connections over time. That way you can control how many bits you can transmit/receive. Think of the way serial EPROMs work. They have very few pins, yet allowing memory densities over a megabyte